# Extrair dados conjuntos de um JSON usando PHP

Tags: php, json, php-7

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de JSON

```
{
  "trophy_name_XPT001": "Text Name 01",
  "trophy_desc_XPT001": "Text Desc 01",
  "throw.except.und": "Error",
  "nav_bunt_852": "Zoom Out",
  "trophy_name_BHTLN": "Text Name 02",
  "trophy_desc_BHTLN": "Text Desc 02",
  "trophy_name_XPT020": "Text Name 03",
  "trophy_desc_XPT020": "Text Desc 03",
  "abc_gama_opt": "Text Random",
  "inpt.hover.ali": "11.02.22.456-896",
  "trophy_name_OPB852": "Text Name 04",
  "trophy_desc_OPB852": "Text Desc 04",
  "trophy_name_XPTHJN": "Text Name 06",
  "trophy_desc_XPTHJN": "Text Desc 06",
  "trophy_name_XPT002": "Text Name 008*01",
  "trophy_desc_XPT002": "Text Desc 008*01",
  "nav_admin": "89652"
}
```

Preciso filtrar apenas os dados que contenham `trophy_name_...` e `trophy_desc_...` e usar um foreach para iterar e juntar os que contém o código igual num unico array

No momento o código é este

```
<?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("texts.json"));

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match_all("/trophy_(name|desc)_(.*.)/", $key, $matches)) {

        $type = $matches['1']['0'];
        $code = $matches['2']['0'];
    }
}
?>
```

E preciso de uma saída neste estilo

```
    /* Objetivo

    Codigo: XPT001 | Nome: Text Name 01 | Descrição: Text Desc 01
    Codigo: BHTLN | Nome: Text Name 02 | Descrição: Text Desc 02
    ....
    Codigo: XPT002 | Nome: Text Name 008*01 | Descrição: Text Desc 008*01

    */
```

Não sei se o `preg_match_all` é o melhor jeito para fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cada chave que começa com "trophy", basta extrair o trecho "name"/"desc" e o respectivo código, e em seguida setar os valores de acordo:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("texts.json"));
$result = [];
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match("/^trophy_(name|desc)_(.+)/", $key, $match)) {
        $campo = $match[1]; // "name" ou "desc"
        $codigo = $match[2];
        $result[$codigo][$campo] = $value;
    }
}
```

Usei o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` que indica o início da string, assim eu pego somente as chaves que começam com "trophy". E usei `.+` (um ou mais caracteres), em vez de `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres) para pegar o código. Mas se quiser, pode ser mais específico (por exemplo, `[A-Z0-9]+` para pegar letras maiúsculas ou dígitos), já que o ponto pega qualquer caractere.

Com isso, a estrutura do array `$result` será:

```
array(6) {
  ["XPT001"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Text Name 01"
    ["desc"]=>
    string(12) "Text Desc 01"
  }
  ["BHTLN"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Text Name 02"
    ["desc"]=>
    string(12) "Text Desc 02"
  }
  etc...
```

Ou seja, cada código aponta para um array contendo as chaves "name" e "desc", e seus respectivos valores.

Uma vez tendo esse array, basta percorrê-lo para imprimir os dados da maneira que quiser. Ex:

```
foreach($result as $code => $vals) {
    echo "Código: {$code} | Nome: {$vals['name']} | Descrição: {$vals['desc']}\n";
}
```

Saída:

```
Código: XPT001 | Nome: Text Name 01 | Descrição: Text Desc 01
Código: BHTLN | Nome: Text Name 02 | Descrição: Text Desc 02
Código: XPT020 | Nome: Text Name 03 | Descrição: Text Desc 03
Código: OPB852 | Nome: Text Name 04 | Descrição: Text Desc 04
Código: XPTHJN | Nome: Text Name 06 | Descrição: Text Desc 06
Código: XPT002 | Nome: Text Name 008*01 | Descrição: Text Desc 008*01
```

---

Em vez de regex, você também pode verificar se a string começa com "trophy" (bastando usar [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) e ver se a posição é zero) e usar [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode) para quebrar as partes:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("texts.json"));
$result = [];
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'trophy') === 0) { // se começa com "trophy"
        list($_, $campo, $codigo) = explode('_', $key);
        $result[$codigo][$campo] = $value;
    }
}
```

E a partir do PHP 8, pode usar [`str_starts_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) no lugar de `strpos`:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("texts.json"));
$result = [];
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (str_starts_with($key, 'trophy')) { // se começa com "trophy"
        list($_, $campo, $codigo) = explode('_', $key);
        $result[$codigo][$campo] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigado!